# Pages stuck in google chrome

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome

I have a very strange problem, sometimes when i'm using facebook the page can suddenly freeze up completely it means I can not click on anything or scroll, all other tabs in Chrome works fine, restarting chrome does not help, this also happens to other pages.

The odd thing is that if I close Chrome and opens Firefox and enter facebook.com sign in so the page is fully loaded (Firefox works fine on facebook), then open chrome then goes to facebook and the page loads fine and works like usual, this solves the problem every time facebook is stuck in chrome.

How can I debug this, I have no idea on what to do.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: Do you think it's somsing with the settings maby, beacuse I reinstalled chrome and copied the old setting over, will try reinstalling with no setting.

Comment: I have now reinstalleed chrome with revo uninstaller. Will report back later, but how can it be that visiting faceboon on firefox fixes the problem.

Comment: Chrome tries to download a site, and for some reason cannot. Firefox can load the page and downloads it to your local cache. When you try again in Chrome, it reads the cache first, and loads successfully. This is just a guess, if anyone else has similar experiences there may be another explanation. Either way the first thing I'd do is clean reinstall Chrome to the latest version and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Chrome also installs to your user hive in Windows by default, so you may want to test creating a new user profile and installing Chrome there. You haven't mentioned what operating system your using though.

Comment: Ohh sorry I am on windows 7. I have reinstalled chrome with revo uninstaller so lets see if this works.

Comment: The problem seams to still exist, have reinstalled chrome so dont know what to do now.

Comment: Still no luck, damn this is fustrating.